# What factors cause something to resist wind?

Tags: forces

*Hi, this is a very basic question from a physics know-nothing. I've tried googling it every way I could think of, but either couldn't find or recognize the answer.  I thought I might have better luck asking someone with the framework already in place. Thanks for your patience.*

---

**The Question:** I want to understand what factors matter when deciding whether a given motionless object will get blown away by a gust of wind, or stay in place, and how those factors relate to each other.

As best I understand, in physics wind is understood as a kind of drag. So what causes an otherwise motionless object to resist drag? Mass? Weight? Surface area? Density? Is it understood as a simple force meeting an object, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In physics, wind is understood as a drift of particles. Basically the air molecules, which are moving due to temperature, on average move in a certain direction (without wind they still move, but on average stay at their position).

Air molecules hitting an object are deflected, causing a force on the object - a drag. How big that force is depends mainly on three factors:

- The number of molecules hitting the object.
- The velocity of the molecules hitting the object.
- The angle under which the molecule hits the object.

Obviously the strength of the wind influences both the velocity and the number of molecules hitting your object, its direction might influence the angle.

The characteristics of your object also influence this force. Let's take a sail as an example.
Size matters here, to be more precise: area. The bigger the sail, the more force. Depending on the wind you might be able to hold a scarf like a sail in the wind, but bigger sails move entire ships across the ocean.
Shape matters as well. If the sail just waves like a flag, the wind "slides along" the sail instead of hitting it directly (remember the angle part?). "Streamlined" objects (e.g. racing cars) especially try find a good shape.

Against all that drag caused by the wind, there are usually other forces.
The weight of an object combined with its friction on the ground. Or some screws/foundations holding it in place. Magnets holding things in place. Or whatever else causes a force on the object.

If your object moves or not is now just a question of which force is stronger and can get quite complicated. Heavy objects might slide away on ice but not on earth. A plastic bag might hang somewhere until the next gust hits. A sail will probably move and take an entire ship with it - but only if the wind hits from the right direction.